# javascript tokenizing strings to cleanup text

Tags: javascript, regex, text-processing

I am having a little bit of trouble trying to clean up some text. I get an input text that I would like to remove all non single space white space characters, remove periods, comma's, etc but not split up words like these:

Ph.D.
teacher's

basically I don't want to remove punctuation that doesn't change the meaning of the word, things like exclamation marks, question marks can go.

I wrote some js regex but I think it's pretty messy. Any advice to clean this up?

```
var cleaned_plaintext = input_text;

cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.toLowerCase();
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/^\s+/mg,"");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/[,:()]/mg,"");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/\|\s+/mg,"");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/\s\-+\s/mg,"");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/\s{2,}/mg,"");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/\.\s+/mg, " ");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/\?/mg, "");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/(\0\r\n|\n|\r|\0)/gm," ");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/\./mg, "");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/[©]\s+/mg, "");
cleaned_plaintext = cleaned_plaintext.replace(/[.,?!:;()–?|$©”“|…]/gm,"");
```

that's a lot of regex and I feel like it could be cleaned up a lot. I am just unsure how. I know this is tagged javascript but if there's another language with better tools, I am willing to work with that as well.

Comment: Don't think this is possible using a regex. You need something that understands the meaning of words: `Ph.D.` and `Sentence one. Sentence two.` would look pretty much the same to a regex - they are just dots surrounded by other characters. No real way of distinguishing whether it's a "legit" dot or not. I suggest writing a BIG list of unit tests with plenty of valid and invalid inputs to verify. Then try and find something that satisfies them.

Comment: @Vld It is 100% possible, and in fact easy to know if punctuation is inside a word. The OP seems to have working (but messy) code.

Comment: @Laurel if you are talking about checking for spacing around a dot `sentence one.sentence two` defeats that. And what if you encounter `Dr. Smith` - you're going to strip off that dot? If doctor is too obvious do recipher without the dot, what about `Rev. Smith`? And what about `Mr F. Bloggs`? Should the _name of a person_ be written without dot, just because of a regex? The token `3` is read "three" but the token `3.` is read as "third", so they are different things. Again, regex doesn't distinguish between them. It's just some dots and other symbols not words with actual meanings.

Comment: @Vld `sentence one.sentence two` is not a valid way to end a sentence, at least in English. The current standard is one space after the period, but two is often accepted due to the change being recent. As for abbreviations, it depends on the OP's use case. It looks like the point is to pre-process the text. Therefore, it depends on what is necessary later on. Also, `3.` would never appear in certain types of texts. It all depends on the context, and the OP is the only one who knows the context at this point.

Comment: "is not a valid way to end a sentence, at least in English" good, now go explain it to every user who wants to enter text in your app. Maybe you can ship a little gnome that jumps out of the monitor and stabs them if they don't type exactly what you want - that would definitely help. In the mean time, you have to accept that what _you_ think and what _the users_ think are going to be different. Also, if "only the OP knows" the context, how is it that you are 100% certain how and why people would be typing in? As I keep repeating - regex doesn't parse meanings only characters.

Comment: @Vld "Input" may refer to things other than *user* input. It may be information from a database, for example. If the input contains the text of scientific research papers from important journals, then it is reasonable to expect that proper English will be used. Please be nice; I have a lot of experience with regex (over 100 score in the tag) and I know what I'm saying.

Comment: @Laurel OK, how _do_ you know what the input is? Your all of "well, it MIGHT be formatted correctly" weight exactly nothing when it also MIGHT not be formatted correctly. And there are plenty of correct usages of punctuation as part of words that cannot be easily distinguished: `Yahoo!` is spelled with an exclamation mark; `A*` - asterisk; `Smith, John` has a significant comma, `Mark Rein•Hagen` spells his name with that dot there, abbreviations can end with a dot-space. All are perfectly valid. All or similar things can show up in "proper" texts. This cannot be solved via regex.

Comment: @Vld I read the question, which asks how to clean up the regex. The input doesn't actually matter, since the output should be the same as whatever the current code outputs. I'm finished discussing this; you should move on too.

Comment: You didn't really "duscuss" it - I gave you a list of things that broke your claim that it's "100% possible" to use regex for any input and you refuted it by narrow and narrowing down your definition of input. And it's still not 100% sure way that it'd work. Regex is a hammer - we all know how why hammers shouldn't be over relied to. This problem is definitely not a nail. I think it's not only wrong but _irresponsible_ to make people not aware of that. And you are being irresponsible for misinforming. Rep means nothing if you don't recognise where regex can and cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can combine a number of the regexes together.

You have these two regexes:

```
/^\s+/mg
/\s{2,}/mg
```

It's equivalent to:

```
/\s{2,}|^\s/mg
```

---

This regex:

```
/\s\-+\s/mg
```

can be written as:

```
/\s-+\s/mg
```

---

I'm not sure what's up with all this:

```
/[©]\s+/mg
/\|\s+/mg
/[,:()]/mg
/\?/mg
/\./mg
/[.,?!:;()–?|$©”“|…]/gm
```

You're removing everything at least *twice*.

Note that `)–?` includes these characters:

`)*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?`

You can get rid of most of those and change your one regex to:

```
/[!(–?$”“…]/mg
```

To handle the 2 symbols where you want to remove an optional trailing space, you could use:

```
/[©|]\s?/mg
```

---

You use these two regexes to find things to replace with a space:

```
/\.\s+/mg
/(\0\r\n|\n|\r|\0)/gm
```

You can combine them, and remove some unneeded things:

```
/\.\s+|\n|\r|\0/mg
```

The best order to run these new regexes:

```
/\.\s+|\n|\r|\0/mg  //remember replace with space!
/\s-+\s/mg
/[©|]\s?/mg
/[!(–?$”“…]/mg
/\s{2,}|^\s/mg
```

You could also chain together the functions, like: `.replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)`. You can decide if that's a good idea or not.